# How to pre check checkboxes with a belongsToMany relationship in a form?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I did some changes in my database layout. The DB was designed with a `belongsTo` relationship. And now it is a `belongsToMany` relationship. So a row can now have more relations then before. Previously i stored the "genre id" on each `$game` row in a `genre_id` column. And that worked, but it was troubeling thus, in my case, a game can have many genres.

**Before the change**, i was able to choose genre from a dropdown list and have the list prechecked.

```
<select
class="block appearance-none w-full bg-gray-200 border border-gray-200 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
name="genre_id"
id="genre_id">
    @foreach($genres as $genre)
        <option value="{{ $genre->id }}" {{ old("genre_id", $game->genre_id) == $genre->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $genre->genre }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And with the **current setup**, I get a collection of `genres` on `$game`.

```
    {
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Mach Rider",
    "slug": "mach-rider",
    "console_id": 1,
    "cover_image": "http://sdb3.test/storage/images/placeholder.png",
    "description": null,
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2017-04-21T07:40:22.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-03-15T10:04:24.000000Z",
    "genres": [
        {
        "id": 36,
        "genre": "Vehicular combat",
        "description": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-12",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-12",
        "pivot": {
            "game_id": 12,
            "genre_id": 36
        }
        },
        {
        "id": 5,
        "genre": "Racing",
        "description": null,
        "created_at": "2020-12-12",
        "updated_at": "2020-12-12",
        "pivot": {
            "game_id": 12,
            "genre_id": 5
        }
        }
    ]
    }
```

Instead of a dropdown, a bunch of checkboxes would be more appropriate. But I cannot get it to work with `old()` and having prechecked genres. I have tried with `in_array()` and `array_intersect`, like this:

```
 @foreach($genres as $genre)
      <div class="flex items-start">
        <div class="flex items-center h-5">
          <input
             id="genre"
             name="genre[]"
             type="checkbox"
             class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded"
             value="{{ $genre->genre }}"
             {{ old("genre", in_array($genre->pluck('genre'), $game->genres->pluck('genre')->toArray())) ? 'checked' : '' }}
                  >
          </div>
         <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
           <p class="text-gray-500">{{ $genre->genre }} ({{ $genre->games_count }})</p>
         </div>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

This I `GameController@edit`

```
public function edit(Game $game)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $game);

    $genres = Genre::withCount('games')->get();

    return view('game.edit.index', compact('game', 'genres'));
}
```

So what I'm asking your help for is, how can I use `old()` with a `belongsToMany` relationship?

## This is my relationships:

`App\Game`

```
public function genres(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
    }
```

`App\Genre`

```
public function games(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Game::class);
    }
```

Table `game_genre`

```
+----+----------+---------+------------+------------+
| id | genre_id | game_id | created_at | updated_at |
+----+----------+---------+------------+------------+
|  1 |        5 |       1 | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
|  2 |       36 |       1 | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
+----+----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Table `genres`

```
+----+------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| id |      genre       | description | created_at | updated_at |
+----+------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Shooter          | NULL        | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
|  2 | Platform         | NULL        | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
|  3 | Beam em up       | NULL        | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
|  4 | Puzzle           | NULL        | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
|  5 | Racing           | NULL        | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
|  6 | Simulation       | NULL        | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
| 36 | Vehicular combat | NULL        | 2020-12-12 | 2020-12-12 |
+----+------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
{{ old("genre", in_array($genre->id, $game->genres->pluck('id')->toArray())) ? 'checked' : '' }}
```

Still not the best solution if your form fails validation.

Comment: Nice! That actually worked! The boxes are pre-checked! Any ideas on how to validate and store? :)

Comment: store it as 
$game->genres()->sync($request->get('genre'));
as for validation..depends on what you want to validate, on other inputs in your request

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm! i meant error handling in the blade file. If I have a validation error, all checkboxeses are ticked, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

For form validation:

```
{{ in_array($genre->id, old('genre', $game->genres->pluck('id')->toArray())) ? 'checked' : '' }}
```